# What will happen to my content if i switch from elementor to simple editor?

Tags: wordpress, builder, elementor

Want to switch my elementor builder interface in simple editor like old Html one on my website [tellthebell](https://www.tellthebelltaco.us)* as my site load's slowly due to this builder. want to know if my content will be loss or just the design will change?

Or suggest something that might help my loading time of site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes agreed with the @cengiz sevimli Not only design will be lost also the content can be deleted. However if you have added any posts it will be saved at backend and you can add it up again from there in the new design.

Answer (score 2):

well, a simple and easiest trick to do is save your content  (Manually save in word doc) by pressing ctrl+A then switch to the old mode of HTML, if you lose your design/ interface..try editing or adding content that you already saved...Also, you can change your theme and again use the same content, etc.. it works very well you just need to be little tricky :P

Answer (score 1):

Frist, you need to perform speed optimization for your website. It will help to load your website as soon as possible.
You can use **Autoptimize** and **WP Rocket** Plugin to boost the speed of your website. 
Second, if you will switch your website from elementor to another builder you will lose complete design. After that, you need to redesign your website.

For check the speed of your website use : https://gtmetrix.com

Answer (score 1):

If you change your builder, you may end up losing your designs. However you can try backing up your builder's raw code by pressing "Use Default Editor" like: [image: design as text]

Comment: I don't have any active backup plans on site, what else is best suitable solution?

Comment: You can copy design text and content of each page to a text file in your local machine if you really want to spend 4-5 hours to change your editor. Then you can install new editor and create every page with this editor and copy its design and content from your local text files.